# MS Access form ID increment

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to set up a simple form in MS access to add a new record to a table full of contact information. Each time I add a new record using the form, I want an ID number field to increment by one against whatever the highest value in the ID field is. The code I have right now seems to be working:

```
Private Sub Contact_ID_Click()

Dim newContactID As Double

newContactID = DMax("[Contact_ID]", "Contacts") + 1

Contact_ID = newContactID

End Sub
```

The problem is that every time I start the database, open up the form in form view and click on the Contact_ID field to increment it, I get the following error message:

"The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Object or class does not support the set of events."

I go to design view, open up the code, and then as soon as I switch back to Form view it's working again. I'd like it to work when the form is opened from scratch as others might be using this form and wouldn't know what to do. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using an autonumber field on your Contacts table?